# Python-Bottle internal Server Error 500 when uploading to S3 bucket and creating an PostgreSQL entry in RDS

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

so i explore the AWS at the moment and have a problem regarding an own little project.

I have a python bottle on an ec2-instance, a S3 bucket for uploads and a RDS instance (postgreSQL).

I have a script which lets me upload images (jpg and png).
Now I want to have an entry in my database for every upload I do.

The connection is established and all rules allow traffic from ec2-instance to S3 bucket, to RDS-instance and back.

After uploading, normally i get a message that it worked out, but now after including code in the python script to Write and Read from the database it just shows Internal Server Error 500.

Before it also put the upload in my S3 bucket, but now it puts it into my ec2-instance directory.
And creates a directory "user_uploads" which, actually should point to the S3 bucket, like it did before including the Code to Read/Write to the DB.

Can someone help me?

`

```
CREATE SCHEMA bottletube;
SET SCHEMA 'bottletube';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image_uploads
(
    id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    category VARCHAR(64)
);
```

`

`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import os
import uuid
import psycopg2
import requests

from bottle import route, run, template, request
from boto3 import resource

BUCKET_NAME = 'python-bottle-hw'  # Replace with your bucket name
SAVE_PATH = 'user_uploads'


@route('/home')
@route('/')
def home():
    # SQL Query goes here later, now dummy data only
    # Read Entries from database
    items = []
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM image_uploads ORDER BY id')
    for record in cursor.fetchall():
        items.append({'id': record[0], 'filename': record[1], 'category': record[2]})
    return template('home.tpl', name='BoTube Home', items=items)


@route('/upload', method='GET')
def do_upload_get():
    return template('upload.tpl', name='Upload Image')


@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload_post():
    category = request.forms.get('category')
    upload = request.files.get('file_upload')

    # Check for errors
    error_messages = []
    if not upload:
        error_messages.append('Please upload a file.')
    if not category:
        error_messages.append('Please enter a category.')

    try:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)
        if ext not in ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'):
            error_messages.append('File Type not allowed.')
    except:
        error_messages.append('Unknown error.')

    if error_messages:
        return template('upload.tpl', name='Upload Image', error_messages=error_messages)

    # Save to SAVE_PATH directory
    if not os.path.exists(SAVE_PATH):
        os.makedirs(SAVE_PATH)
    save_filename = f'{name}_{time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")}{ext}'
    with open(f'{SAVE_PATH}{save_filename}', 'wb') as open_file:
        open_file.write(upload.file.read())

 if ext == '.png':
        content_type = 'image/png'
    else:
        content_type = 'image/jpeg'

    # Upload to S3
    data = open(SAVE_PATH + save_filename, 'rb')
    s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=f'user_uploads/{save_filename}',
                                               Body=data,
                                               Metadata={'Content-Type': content_type},
                                               ACL='public-read')

    # Write to DB
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO image_uploads (url, category) VALUES ('user_uploads/{save_filename}', '{category}');")
    connection.commit()

    # Return template
    return template('upload_success.tpl', name='Upload Image')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Connect to DB
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", host="endpoint of my database", password="here would be my password", database="bottletube")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SET SCHEMA 'bottletube';")
    connection.commit()

    # Connect to S3
    s3_resource = resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')

    # Needs to be customized
    # run(host='your_public_dns_name',
    run(host=requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname').text,
        port=80)
```

`

So this is my code, i know, never include passwords in code, i know how AWS secretmanager works but wanted to check function before i do that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: @Chris can you tell me where i find them? Sorry new to coding, still learning basics

Comment: EC2 is a virtual server, there are any number of ways you might have configured it to run your application. Are you using Nginx? Apache? Something else? Search for "nginx error logs" or similar and see what you can find.